# Woocommerce: admin Orders list - Preview - rename bottom buttons

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

in

```
Woocommerce 3.3.0
```

In the order list.
When you click on the [the eye](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu4Km.jpg) it shows an AJAX preview of the order.

The action is handled by:
[get_order_preview_actions_html( WC_Order $order )](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Admin_List_Table_Orders.html#519-561)
in

```
WC_Admin_List_Table_Orders.php
```

How do I unset the `"completed"` button,

and rename the `"processing"` button to `"approved"`

in my `functions.php`?

Thanks.

Comment: unset the "completed" button means you want to remove this button?

Comment: Yes.  Else I would like to like it to appear only if ( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) )

Comment: I swept this under the rug with the below solution.  Still would love a better answer.  :/

Answer (score 0):

Blah!

Lazy... Just replace the whole thing for now.
If somebody can figure out a cleaner, prettier, safer way...  Please.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_order_preview_actions','remove_complete',20,2); function remove_complete( $actions, $order ){
                $actions        = array();
        $status_actions = array();

        if ( $order->has_status( array( 'pending', 'on-hold' ) ) ) {
            $status_actions['processing'] = array(
                'url'    => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_mark_order_status&status=processing&order_id=' . $order->get_id() ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-status' ),
                'name'   => __( 'Approve', 'woocommerce' ),
                'action' => 'processing',
            );
        }

        if ( $order->has_status( array( 'processing' ) ) ) {
            $status_actions['complete'] = array(
                'url'    => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_mark_order_status&status=completed&order_id=' . $order->get_id() ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-status' ),
                'name'   => __( 'Complete', 'woocommerce' ),
                'action' => 'complete',
            );
        }


        if ( $status_actions ) {
            $actions['status'] = array(
                'group'   => __( 'Change status: ', 'woocommerce' ),
                'actions' => $status_actions,
            );
        }

    return $actions; }
```